# RESTful url for printing a resource

Tags: rest

I have a Stock resource which is obviously an item of stock and it can be accessed by..

```
[Get] /stock/{stockId}
```

And I have a printer resource which is a network printer somewhere and it can be accessed by..

```
[Get] /printer/{printerId}
```

And I have a Template which points to a template file on the server

```
[Get] template/{templateId}
```

Now what I want to do is be able to send a request to a printer to print a certain stock item using a certain template.

My first thought would be

```
/printer/{printerId}/printstock?stockId=1&templateId=1
```

So my questions are -

When it finishes printing it will update the stock item to say it has been printed does this mean it should be a POST (or should it be a PUT?)

Are actions such as the "printstock" in the URL the correct way to go about this?

Should Stock be part of the main Url rather than in the querystring?

Comment: I flagged this and I don't think it is a good question for SO as it is primarily based on opinions. From a technical point of view you can do however you like and if it is a POST or PUT doesn't really matter. However, there are a lot of conventions out there how to do stuff like that, but there are not exactly _rules_. I would always avoid query parameters for stuff that is required and if I add a new print job I would make it a POST.

Comment: If we are talking about REST, HTTP verbs (`GET`, `PUT`, `POST`, etc.) *do* matter. REST is not RPC.

Comment: @dirkk I agree this is probably more of an opinion based question and happy for it to be removed if people think it should however I think Lutz Horn answer below is the right one and set me on the right track I think so thanks.

Comment: @LutzHorn Of course they matter, but which one to apply to a particular situation  isn't strictly defined. It is a architectural decision.

Comment: For example, there would be nothing wrong with modeling Lutz' POST as `/printjobs/1234/1/1` without any post data. Both are correct, mostly a matter of opinion which one to prefer.

Comment: @dirkk true but I think the key was the idea of having a /printjobs/.... which is much better than my initial idea so I think in that sense there is a right answer. You are however correct that the implementation is opinion based and not a great question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Model the print job as a separate resource. You create a new print job by `POST`ing to a collection resource that represents all print jobs.

Request:

```
POST /printjobs
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "printer": 1234,
  "stock": 1,
  "template": 1
}
```

Response:

```
201 Created
Location: /printjobs/42
```

Then your client could `GET`  the state of the print job.

```
GET /printjobs/42

200 OK
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "id", 42,
  "state": "PRINTING",
  "printer": 1234,
  "stock": 1,
  "template": 1
}
```

After the job has finished, the sate could change to `PRINTED` and the state of the stock could change in a similar way.